# Check For Special Characters in Emails

Tags: apex, trigger, string, before-trigger, substring

I'm having a business requirement of searching special characters in Email Field(before @domain.com)in a trigger.

For Ex: if a email is like this (t#@est@gmail.com).it should be able to identify the'#@' and make that email field blank.Is there any way available to identify the special characters before '@gmail.com'.

Comment: Use regular expression..Using that you can Identify it

Comment: THanks ..I'm using the patter class to identify Characters.

Comment: system.debug('@@@'+pattern.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}', 'te@stt@skoda.co.au'));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.containsNone()` to check whether a string contains any prohibited characters, or `String.containsOnly()` to check that it only contains a specific set of characters. That said, be aware that email addresses are a good deal more flexible than you might think, and special characters aren't necessarily invalid.

Regular expressions are generally not a good fit for validating email addresses, which is surprisingly tricky. There's a lot of edge cases that are perfectly valid but that your regex in the comments will not match. Your regex, for example, won't match `john.smith+stuff@gmail.com`, which is not only valid but common, or `webmaster@company.cloud`. (There are now [a lot of TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains), not all of which are 2-4 characters long).

For more on *why* parsing and validating email addresses is really hard, and most validation is too strict or just plain wrong, see for example [this article](https://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/), or read the relevant RFCs 822, 2821, 2822, 3696.