# RegEx for UserName format

Tags: validation, user

My Requirement is while creating a user if user Id is not in corrected format then Validation message should be display o UserName  Field.

so if my email address is **abc.def@xyz.com** then my User name must be **abc.def@xyz.com.xyzs**

***User name must contains Email address followed by .xyzs***

I am trying to user below formula but it is not working.

```
NOT(REGEX(Username, "^[A-Z0-9._%+-/!#$%&'*=?^_`{|}~]+@[xyz]+.[a-z]{2,4}+.[xyzs]"))
```

Can someone please suggest what needs to be modified?

Comment: I've written an [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/212528/check-for-special-characters-in-emails/212561#212561) previously about why it's hard and unwise to use a regex to validate an email address. Would it be sufficient for your purposes to check for the suffix ".xyzs"?

Comment: yes it would be sufficient to check for .xyzs but if someone written as .xyzab then validation should be thrown if someone writes .xzys.ab then it no validation. The answer that you have posted is for trigger and I am using here Validation rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your email address will already be validated by Salesforce. As @DavidReed says, it is very complicated to create your own regex for that. As your email address is by definition valid you can just check if the username is the email adres plus your '.xyzs'.

I think this should work for your use case?

```
NOT(Email = UserName + '.xyzs')
```

Comment: Thank You So much it works. Expression worried for me is NOT(UserName = Email+ '.xyzs')

Comment: @sfdcbeast Happy to help!